# Java methods thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a scenario, searched quite a bit, but did not get satisfactory answer.

There is a service class, WebserviceInvokerService,

```
class WebserviceInvokerService {
    @Override
    public void synchronized callBackFun() {...}
}
```

callBackFun ==> is the function which gets called when an event (some event) occurs.

In callBackFun I check DB and accordingly do a service call (no instance members of the class are involved in this business).

I have made callBackFun synchronized. There is a possibility that, multiple instances of WebserviceInvokerService will be created and callBackFun will be called on those objects.

I want callBackFun to be called "synchronously" across the objects. So will the "synchronized" for callBackFun will make any sense in such scenario.

Comment: You must synchronize whenever an object's mutable state is shared by  2 or more threads.  Since you haven't shown us or told us about the state that you're trying to protect, it is not possible to answer your question.

Comment: If you want synchronize across objects,  you should use synchronized(WebserviceInvokerService.class){...} inside the callBackFun method

Comment: It sounds a bit like you're adding `synchronized` without really understanding why. What's the mutable state that the method changes making it thread-unsafe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you java multiple instances WebserviceInvokerServices the methods will be synchronized in each of these instances, but not across the instances.

What you might be looking for is a Lock.

You can try this:

```
private final static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

@Override
public void callBackFun() {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        // Do things here
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Added the final keyword as mentioned by @Wyzard

Comment: And the lock should almost certainly be declared `final`, because you don't ever want to replace it with a different lock while the program is running.

Answer (score 2):

To synchronize across instances, you  should use synchronized with static reference.

```
class WebserviceInvokerService {
    @Override
    public void callBackFun() {
        synchronized(WebserviceInvokerService.class) {... } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than synchronizing on the class object itself, it may be better to use a `private static final` variable.  The class object is accessible throughout the whole application, and other parts of the application might be synchronizing on it for other, unrelated purposes that shouldn't interact with the class's own internal self-synchronization.

Comment: as mentioned in the answer by @Lµk4s

Answer (score -1):

Since `callBackFun` does not use instance members (as per post: no instance members of the class are involved in this business)

you can put this code in `static synchronized` method so that classlevel lock will be present. Call it from your instance method

```
public synchronized void callBackFun() {
    actualFunLogic();
}

private static synchronized void actualFunLogic()
{
   .....
}
```